# save console output of programm to file - not simplte 2>&1

Tags: linux, console, io-redirection, soundtouch

i want to analyze multiple mp3 files and get the bpm of the files. Therefore i'm using soundstretch. At first i'm converting the mp3 files using sox

```
sox -t mp3 -r 44100 -c 2 file.mp3 -t wav file3.wav
```

after this i want to analyze the track with soundstretch

```
soundstretch file.wav -bpm
```

this also gives me the result in the console. But i'm not able to redirect the printed response to a file. i already tried stuff like

```
soundstretch file.wav -bpm > file.mp3.bpm
soundstretch file.wav -bpm 2>&1 > file.mp3.bpm
```

the only result is, that the messages are displayed in the console and there is a empty file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch it around if you want one file

```
soundstretch file.wav -bpm > file.mp3.bpm  2>&1
```

or use two file two files:

```
soundstretch file.wav -bpm 2> file.mp3.err > file.mp3.bpm
```

Comment: Basically > goes to stdout and 2> goes to stderr.  Actually in your case it looks like there is not stdout since you had an empty file and could just redirect stderr alone.  `soundstretch file.wav -bpm 2> file.mp3.bpm`

Comment: soundstretch file.wav -bpm 2> file.bpm - thanks didn't notice that everything is responded via error

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the soundstretch as

soundstretch inputFile outputFile options

ex. : soundstretch Sample.waw out.txt -bpm

Comment: then soundstretch converts a 1:1 copy ;)